# style mui multiple autocomplete values in textField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I want to create an autocomplete multiple but with a comma in selected values. When I choose multiple values, it makes bigger the component.
But I want to make autocomplete just like select with multiple option.
First image shows how autocomplete behaves in multiple selection. Second image, what I want when multiple selection occurs.
my code:

```js
<Autocomplete
                    disablePortal
                    id="serviceCities"
                    name="serviceCities"
                    value={formik.values.serviceCities}
                    onChange={(e, value) => formik.setFieldValue("serviceCities", value)}
                    options={cities}
                    loading={true}
                    loadingText="loading..."
                    multiple={true}
                    getOptionLabel={type => type.name}
                    sx={{ width: "100%", mt: "4%" }}
                    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params}
                        label="provide services in"
                        placeholder="type name of cities"
                        sx={{ ...styles.autoComplete, width: "100%" }}
                        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                        error={formik.touched.serviceCities && Boolean(formik.errors.serviceCities)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.serviceCities && formik.errors.serviceCities}
                    />}
                />
```

[how mui autocomplete multipla select shows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBxnY.png)

[the behavior I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC0Dg.png)

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display text instead of Chips, you can use the **renderTags** prop of `<Autocomplete>` to render `<span>` elements instead of `<Chip>` components. (Chip components are rendered by default when Autocomplete is used with the *multiple* prop.)

This [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kofeigen/51npd49L/) has a demonstration. (Click "Run" to start the demo.) The code in the demo is compiled, but copied below. *index.jsx* was compiled to the file name **index.js** and located in the same directory as **index.html**.

The part of your question that says: *When I choose multiple values, it makes bigger the component.* might need more clarification. The Material-UI `<Input>` component automatically increases in height to accommodate selected options that are too long for the configured width. If you want to increase the width dynamically you could calculate a value for the `width` property of **sx** in the `<Stack>` component. This line in *index.jsx* would need to be updated:

```js
<Stack spacing={3} sx={ { width: 500 } }>
```

There could be different approaches for calculating width based on the number of characters in the options, the number of options in each row of the `<Input>` component, etc.

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Material-UI Autocomplete Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="testContainer" class="testContainer"></div>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
        <noscript> Please enable javascript to view the site </noscript>
    </body>

</html>
```

### index.jsx

```js
// index.jsx

import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const container = document.getElementById( 'testContainer' );

import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';


export default function ListItems() {

    /**
     * Select option items in the drop-down list.
     */
    const options = [
        { id: 0, value: 'Waldorf', someProperty: 'someValue' },
        { id: 1, value: 'Wright', someProperty: 'someValue' },
        { id: 2, value: 'Edlezold', someProperty: 'someValue' }
    ];

    /**
     * Items selected by the user for display in the input field.
     */
    const [ list, setList ] = React.useState( [] );

    function handleChange( event, inputs, reason ) {
        if ( 'selectOption' == reason ) {
            setList( inputs );
        } else if ( 'clear' == reason ) {
            setList( [] );
        }
    }

    return (
        <Stack spacing={3} sx={ { width: 500 } }>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="tags-filled"
                filterSelectedOptions={ true }
                fullWidth={ false }
                options={ options }
                getOptionLabel={ ( option ) => option.value }
                value={ list }
                isOptionEqualToValue={ ( option, value ) => option.value == value.value }
                renderInput={ ( params ) => {
                    return (
                        <TextField
                            { ...params }
                            variant="filled"
                            label="Autocomplete Test"
                            placeholder="Select item"
                            helperText="Select item from list"
                        />
                    );
                } }
                renderTags={ ( list ) => {
                    let displayList = list.map( ( item ) => item.value ).join( ', ' );
    
                    // Render <span> elements instead of <Chip> components.
                    return <span>{ displayList }</span>;
                } }
                onChange={ handleChange }
            />
        </Stack>
    );
}


/**
 * Inject component into DOM
 */
ReactDOM.render(
    <ListItems />,
    container
);
```

Comment: thank you very much! work as expected!